# HashMap to String Rust

Tags: rust

How can I turn a HashMap into a string in rust?

Worst case scenario, if it is not possible to stringify a HashMap (could be done looping through the keys and values but it is too much)... How can I turn it into a JSON?

In my case I have `{9a6743c2-7c49-4c4d-a136-44114ca50246: "Larry", 9a6743c2-7c49-4c4d-a136-44114ca50236: "Farry"}` as my hash map... two of to fields, entries{id: name}. I wanna send that to a client, so I could JSON-ify it or String-if it.

Comment: HashMap into string... There are million ways you can do that. It will help if you will provide an example of input+output. And what you tried, where did you get stuck, etc..

Comment: you probably want to look at the [`serde`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/) crate if you want JSON

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I appreciate your interest in helping, I have updated the question by adding what you requested.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows Unfortunately it seems near impossible to do so with serde as it can be seen here https://users.rust-lang.org/t/serde-hashmap-serialization-key-error/49776/10

Comment: Can you show the structs in your code? And the linked users.rust-lang.org does not say it is impossible, just impossible with non-strings key which I don't think is the case here (if it is, you can't serialize to json anyway).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I am not mapping any data to structs, I never believed I needed to do such thing (side note, if it is extremely bad practice to not map data to structs or use an ORM feel welcomed to tell me). I will try what that article recommends just to see then.

Comment: @XaviFont If you have a `HashMap<String, String>` then you can literally just call [`serde_json::to_string()`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.to_string.html) on it.

Comment: @cdhowie I updated the question, maybe that will give a better context

Comment: Surprisingly, this doesn't seem to have been answered yet directly ... there is deserialization and a bunch of specialized questions, but I couldn't find a direct duplicate of this question. Will create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`serde_json`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) crate for this purpose.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut data: HashMap<&'static str, i32> = HashMap::new();
    data.insert("purpose", 42);
    data.insert("nice", 69);

    let serialized_data = serde_json::to_string(&data).unwrap();
    println!("{}", serialized_data);
}
```

```json
{"nice":69,"purpose":42}
```

Comment: @XaviFont the opposite is of course also possible, you can use serde_json for converting the json back to the struct.

Comment: @XaviFont sidenote #2: this is of course possible for every struct that implements `Serialize`, you don't need a `HashMap` for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your map to a `String` in a format other than JSON, you can use the [Itertools trait join method](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn try_stringify() {
    let mut data = HashMap::new();
    data.insert("purpose", 42);
    data.insert("nice", 69);

    let serialized_data = data.iter().map(|(k,v)| format!("{}={}", k, v)).join(", ");
    println!("{}", serialized_data);
}
```

Outputs:

```
nice=69, purpose=42
```